# infinite dimensional representations of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Every representation of a finite group where the degree of the representation is finite can be a unitary matrix by the similarity transformation.

Now I wonder what infinite dimensional representations of a finite group looks like.

Is it shown by the infinite dimensional matrix?
And Can it also be a unitary matrix by the similarity transformation?

Or is it only limited to the direct sum of finite representations?

Comment: Any infinite-dimensional representation of a finite group $G$ is still a direct sum of irreducible representations of $G$, which are all finite dimensional.

Comment: Thanks. How could you prove it? Please tell me some ideas, theorems, or books to figure it out. I couldn't find any statement which tells about general infinite-dimentional representation of a finite group.

Comment: A much stronger statement is that all representations of compact groups are sums of irreps (at least in characteristic 0), and you might find more references for that. Specifically to finite groups, you can use Maschke's Lemma to split off irreps from your big rep.

Comment: I think this is best understood in the context of semisimple rings (of which the group algebra of your finite group is an example). See for example the first two sections of chapter I in Noncommutative Algebra by Dennis and Farb. This may seem too general for your particular problem, but it is well worth the read.

Comment: >>user263190 Thanks. Now I would understand it if I could prove that all irreps are finite-dimensional. How could you show that?

Comment: >>user218931 Thanks. I found the book is in the university's library. So I will see it tomorrow.